# System.Windows.Forms.Timer is not Working in my WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-rest

I have created a restful WCF service.Whenever client is calling this service method i have started a Timer with certain interval like below

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(attempt);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
var tempAttempt = new TempAttempt
{
    AlertInformationId = currentAlertId,
    Attempt = GetAttemptId(attempt),
    Status = false,
    TimerId = "Timer" + currentAlertId.ToString()
};

if (CreateNewAttempt(tempAttempt))
{
    timer.Tag = tempAttempt.TimerId;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //blah blah          
    Timer t = (Timer)sender;
}
```

After starting the timer the tick is not happened after that particular interval.How can i resolve this?

My Service

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/PushNotification")]
[OperationContract]
void PushNotification(MailInformation mailInformations);
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Forms.Timer is the wrong class for a service.

try System.Threading.Timer instead.

Comment: in my service i need to create multiple timers and also i need to save the timer id. In System.Windows.Timers there is a property called Tag for setting a name. in system.Threading.Timer how can i set a unique name for saving?.

Comment: you use the Object state in the constructor.

public Timer (
 TimerCallback callback,
 Object state,
 int dueTime,
 int period
)

your TimerCallback-delegate gets the object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From this link[Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.

Meaning that you cannot use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in this case, it wont work.